# What is the proper term for an API designed around the dotted notation?

Tags: api

I plan to ask another question on Stackoverflow but want to use the correct term. In recent years many APIs have been designed to support the following usage where a common type is returned.

```
var query= myList.Where(p=>p.X == "abc")
                   .Where(p=>p.BirthDate.Year == 1999)
                   .Where(p=>p.Y == 123 )
                   .Where(p=>p.Z == DateTime.Now );
```

What is the accepted software engineering term for this API style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is typically known as a "Fluent" interface, where methods on an instance return the instance itself, allowing chaining like your example.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: More stellar service from Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The concept your talking about is [Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)

x0n is correct that is a concept used in a Fluent Interface.

Comment: True, the code sample employs method chaining, but he asked about the API style. APIs like this are usually described as "Fluent APIs," not "Method Chaining APIs."